# Does Biff retain any knowledge of the DeLorean at the end of the Back To The Future trilogy?

Tags: back-to-the-future

Bear with me...

At the start of BttF1 we have Biff, who is a bully and dominates George McFly.  Lets call this one **Biff-1-original**.  We never see Biff-1-original again, his behaviour and character is changed due to the course of events in the following movies.

At the end of BttF1 we have a different version of Biff, lets call him **Biff-1-wimp**, who is subservient to the now rich and famous author George McFly.

Biff-1-wimp sees the flying DeLorean at the start of BttF2 and comments *"a flying DeLorean? What the hells going on here?"*.

During BttF2 in 2015, old man Biff, lets call him **Biff-2**, steals the DeLorean after seeing it and commenting to himself "A DeLorean, I havent seen one of those in..." and refreshing old memories, then overhearing Doc and Marty discussing it as a time machine.

Biff-2 travels back to 1955, gives young himself, who we shall call **Biff-0**, the almanac and returns to 2015, and dies/fades out.

Ignore everything that happens in the alternate 1985 where **Biff-1-alternate** is rich, that has no bearing on this other than to set the scene for the rest of the movie - skip ahead to Marty and Doc going back to 1955 to try and retrieve the almanac.

In 1955, Marty retrieves the almanac from the car, and Biff-0 (same Biff-0 from the first movie, there is no alternate here) sees the DeLorean flying above him moments before crashing his car into the manure truck.

The DeLorean is hit by lightning and goes back to 1885, Marty follows, the events of BttF3 occur.

At the end of BttF3, Marty is returned to the original 1985 timeline, where his father George McFly is still rich and famous, his mother is still thin, and his siblings are still successful.  He picks up Jennifer from the porch.

But the Biff in this 1985 is still subservient Biff from the end of BttF1 - Biff-1-wimp - and there is a direct lineage between Biff-0 and Biff-1-wimp, which means by this point he would have seen a flying DeLorean twice (beginning and end of BttF2), and a time travelling DeLorean once (beginning of BttF2).

***Is there any canon reason in the films to suggest why Biff-1-wimp has retained no knowledge of something fantastical that he has now witnessed twice?***

I hope you all kept up with me on that journey, and welcome edits to make it clearer.  Perhaps a diagram is in order...

Comment: 1955 Biff only saw the DeLorean from below, and it was a shape outside his experience at that point, so even if he still saw the flying DeLorean in the 1985 of the final timeline, I think it's unlikely he'd make the connection that he'd seen the same vehicle in 1955. It is possible that when 2015 rolls around in the new timeline, Marty and Doc will still arrive on schedule and Biff's memory of the flying DeLorean in 1985 will lead him to tail them again, but even if he took the almanac and took it to 1955, it's part of this timeline's history that Marty gets it back from young Biff.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I agree with what you said. However I suspect we have to assume the new adventure in updated 2015 will have no more consequence than rich Marty's unseen 1955 adventure.  The BTTF universe just doesn't spiral into chaotic attractors / butterfly curve timelines as much as it should :-)

Comment: @lucasbachmann In the [official BTTF FAQ](http://bttf.wikidot.com/official-bttf-faq) by Gale & Zemeckis, in section 1.19 they talk about a "Self-Preservation Instinct of the Space-Time Continuum" which would be one way of explaining why there's no butterfly effect, that history tends to "get back on track" if nothing too drastic gets changed. I also wrote up a long post [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122291/22250) where I speculated about what a time traveler remembers if they appear in multiple iterations of the timeline (like Marty and Doc appearing in the final timeline's 2015).

Comment: I've always wondered how Biff-2 drove the stolen Delorean back to the future on the timeline where Doc and Marty were, instead of the future of the timeline Biff-2 had created by giving Biff-1-alternate the sports almanac.

Comment: @StanleyWebb lots of stuff on that in other questions - the general consensus is that there is only one “live” timeline, and changes caught up in a ripple effect, so there was no “other timeline” to return to.

Comment: I think readability could be improved by using years instead of numbers, e.g. 1985-Biff-original, 1985-Biff-wimp, and so on.

Comment: @StanleyWebb Gale & Zemeckis answer that one in [section 1.9 of the official FAQ](http://bttf.wikidot.com/official-bttf-faq#toc8) that I linked in an earlier comment, apparently the ripple effect causes the world to change around Marty and Doc while they're still in 2015, so that right before they head back in time they are actually in 2015-A, which apparently doesn't look visibly different from the original 2015 (maybe once Biff died, things started to get back to normal in Hill Valley).